# Mask a python submodule from its package's __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

### Short version

A specific setup requires me to create local variables in `__init__.py` that shall mask modules from the same package.

E.g. the variable `y` (in the local context of `__init__.py`) shall hide the module `y.py`. The statement `import x.y` shall yield the local variable instead of loading the module.

*If you do not want to read about the specific setup, scroll down to the question; it is understandable without the details.*

### Detailed description

I have implemented a set of Python 2.7 packages, each of which may require individual configuration settings. For convenience, I was planning to provide configuration defaults *per package* that can be locally overwritten by whoever uses one of the packages.

*(The rationale for this is to distribute default settings when deploying an app to a machine running a specific environment (a server, workstation, laptop, etc.), but at the same time to allow overriding configurations without messing up the local repository or resetting local adaptions on code updates.)*

The directory structure example is:

```
~/pkg/
  |
  +- package_a/
  |    |
  |    +- __init__.py
  |    +- mod_x.py
  |    +- mod_y.py
  |
  +- package_b/
  |    |
  |    +- __init__.py
  |    +- mod_z.py
  |
  +- config/
  |    |
  |    +- __init__.py
  |    +- package_a.py # Should locally override <pkg>_sample.py
  |    +- package_a_sample.py
  |    +- package_b_sample.py
  |
  +- test_this.py
```

I'd like to access the settings stored under `config/` like regular module imports, e.g.:

```py
# ~/pkg/test_this.py
import config.package_a as cfg_a
```

... but have it implicitly switch to the overriding file, if it exists.

### My solution approach

In order to somehow automate the process, I am dynamically creating local variables pointing to the correct configuration file imports. Using the `imp` package, I can import a module and specifically naming it at the same time. *(I.e. at runtime, you cannot distinguish whether `<pkg>_sample.py` or `<pkg>.py` was loaded to serve the configuration.)*

I finally ended up with this:

```py
# ~/pkg/config/__init__.py
import os
import imp

__all__ = ['datastore']
_cfgbase = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for cfgmodule in __all__:
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(_cfgbase, cfgmodule + '.py')):
        locals()[cfgmodule] = imp.load_source(
            cfgmodule, os.path.join(_cfgbase, cfgmodule + '.py'))
    else:
        locals()[cfgmodule] = imp.load_source(
            cfgmodule, os.path.join(_cfgbase, cfgmodule + '_sample.py'))
```

This actually creates a local reference to the required source files (omitting `<pkg>_sample.py` when `<pkg>.py` is existing in `config/`.

I can use it from other modules/scripts if using `from config import package_a as cfg_a`.

### The question

Essentially, this question may fall back to the well-known `import x.y vs from x import y`-thing.

**But** there is a difference here.

I know that `import x.y` requires `y` to be a module. Is there **any possibility** to hide a module in its package's `__init__.py` and to provide a local variable instad *on import*?

- `from x import y` yields the local variable `y` from `x`'s `__init__.py`
- `import x.y` **always** imports the module, even if a local variable `y` exists in `__init__.py`.

I cannot force everyone to always use the former import statement, people like to use the latter one in their code.

Any advise here?

*Edited: Fixed title. Sorry.*

### The solution

Thanks @martijn-pieters for pointing out `sys.modules`.

Actually, my approach would have worked perfectly without explicitly adding the new import to `sys.modules`, as I just failed at properly naming the new imports:

```
locals()[cfgmodule] j= imp.load_source(
    'config.' + cfgmodule, os.path.join(_cfgbase, cfgmodule + '.py'))
```

This solves the issue, as it does not register the new submodule with its *canonical* name (here: `package_a`) but registers it as a submodule of my `config` package.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would help us if you can explain why do you need/want to do this?

Comment: @TomDalton maybe I wasn't clear enough about this. I want all code to be and behave exactly the same, no matter whether a user has made a local config copy for individual changes or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`import x.y` does not really require `y` to be a module. `import x.y` looks up the `'x'` and `'x.y'` keys in the `sys.modules` structure. If both are found, then `x` is bound to `sys.modules['x']`. Only if `'x.y'` does not exist, is Python going to look for a module to load.

The trick then, is to stuff your `y` into `sys.modules`:

```
sys.modules['x.y'] = y
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, I run into other problems with this solution.
This masks installed packages from my `site-packages`, if names collide **partially**:

`import config.celery as cfg_ce; 
print(celery)` yields:
`<module 'celery' from '~/pkg/config/celery_sample.py'>`

I think this results from my `imp.load_source(...)` statements and their given names in `__init__.py`