# Conditionally override python module on import: Design issues

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

in my setup/design, requesting a module of a subpackage automatically loads all other modules from that package. I seek a way to circumvent this.

### Disclaimer

*A few months ago, I asked a question which is related. However, since this issue is new and different, I created this as a new question.*

*For those who want to read on the previous problem and attempt, see [Mask a python submodule from its package's `__init__.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266878/mask-a-python-submodule-from-its-packages-init-py)*

### The Setup

In one of my packages, I have a subpackage called `config` holding a bunch of config files for other submodules and subpackages:

```
mypackage
 |
 +-- subpkg_a
 |    |
 |    +-- __init__.py
 |    +-- <some modules here>.py
 |
 +-- config
 |    |
 .    +-- __init__.py
 .    +-- subpkg_a_sample.py
      +-- .gitignore (ignores everything except __init__ or *_sample.py)
```

### The Requirement

Since the above setup resides in a repository, colleagues can (and shall) clone it in order to use `mypackage` on their local systems. However, their configuration may be different, which is why I want to provide the ability to override the sample config given in `*_sample.py` and have them provide their own configuration file *only locally*.

The rationale is that I want people to contribute code where they can use config settings directly like this (in order to keep the code as general as possible):

```py
from config import subpkg_a as conf_a
print(conf_a.MY_CONFIG_SETTING)
```

However, if they have to make local adaptions to the configuration files to fit certain settings to their local setup, they **should not have to change `*_sample.py`**, as it is part of the repository and contains general-purpose settings and examples. And, if they would change the `*_sample.py` config file, there are always users who accidently check in their local changes (especially deletions) and thus need to be protected from themselves...

**Thus, I need the possibility to override the `*_sample.py` with a local copy, if a local copy is present, and otherwise load `*_sample.py` when the certain config is imported.**

### The Solution I Came Up With

Currently, I am using the following code inside `config/__init__.py`:

```py
import os
import sys
import imp
import re

# Extend the __all__ list for all sub-packages that provide <pkg>_sample.py config files
__all__ = []
_cfgbase = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
_r = re.compile('^(?P<key>.+?)_sample\.py$')
for f in os.listdir(_cfgbase):
    m = _r.match(f)
    if m: __all__.append(m.group('key'))

# Load local override file, if any. Otherwise load respective *_sample.py
for cfgmodule in __all__:
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(_cfgbase, cfgmodule + '.py')):
        locals()[cfgmodule] = imp.load_source('mypackage.config.' + cfgmodule, os.path.join(_cfgbase, cfgmodule + '.py'))
    else:
        locals()[cfgmodule] = imp.load_source('mypackage.config.' + cfgmodule, os.path.join(_cfgbase, cfgmodule + '_sample.py'))
```

What this code does, is:

1. Scan the directory of *this* `__init__.py` for files that end in `_sample.py` and store their name (i.e. everything before `_sample.py`) in the package's `__all__` list. These are the packages for which there are config files available that can be loaded.
2. Iterate over the `__all__` list and freshly import the local override, if there is any, or import the respective `*_sample.py` otherwise. No matter which file was imported, it is made accessible under the name *without the `_sample.py` extension* via the config module. I have done this to keep the code that relies on the config module as clean and generic as possible.

### Finally, the Problem

The issue I now am facing is, that even when a user only imports the configuration for a single subpackage, i.e. `from config import subpkg_a as conf_a`, all other configurations that are available in that directory are immediately loaded as well.

This behavior is obvious by the conditional import in my `__init__.py` (see above). But since there are configuration files for subpackages, that rely on other imports (e.g. `celery` or `mpl_toolkits.basemap`) and that may require a significant effort to be installed under certain environments, any user that just needs a fraction of the configs and subpackages is required to install *all* packages and modules that are imported in a configuration file. Even if the user and his/her respective code does not require the respective config.

I feel like having established a poor design, but I do not know how to do better. So I ask you:

**Do you see any possibility to change the config's `__init__.py` (or even the entire setup) such that it does not load all config files when a user requests a single one?**

I am grateful for hints and answers of any kind. Cheers!

Comment: Alternative approach: import a `local_config.py` if it exists (use `try..except` and have its names override the other config. Do so explicitly.

Comment: Why is that a limitation? Just have your colleagues apply the local configuration explictly. `import local_conf`, and in `local_conf` import the desired `*_sample` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make local configuration *explicit*.

Have people that want to override configuration create a `local_config.py` file. You can add that to `.gitignore`. Have users import **that** module in their own code.

At the top of the `local_config.py` module, teach your users to import the desired sample config:

```
from config.subpkg_a_sample import *
```

Note the `import *` here. Now *all names from `subpkg_a_sample`* are imported into `local_config`. The user can easily override anything they need to. Then in the rest of the software, use

```
try:
    import local_config as config
except ImportError:
    warn('No local configuration available')
    import config.default_config as config
```

or similar approaches to get a default configuration in place.

Another approach is to add:

```
try:
    from local_config import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

to all your `*_sample.py` modules, making those modules responsible for applying local configuration. That way names are also overridden by local configuration.

Requiring users to create a `local_config.py` is no more strenuous to what you already have, where you ask users to pick a sample config and provide overrides for that you magically interpolate.

Comment: Okay, this is a really good hint as a starting point! The only thing is that the config package holds sample configs for more than just a few other packages (so far, it has 10-15 `*_sample.py` files) -- am I wrong seeking for a generic solution where one simply can `from config import xyz`, no matter whether there are local changes or not?

Comment: @jbndlr: I prefer staying away from 'magic' like this, as it is fragile. It sounds as if you are building a  framework (reusable pieces) requiring configuration. What is wrong with requiring the user to explicitly configure? Django requires you to create a configuration module. `Flask` gives you various mechanisms to define configuration you then pass to it explicitly. Pyramid requires you to define an `.ini` file for configuration, etc.

Comment: @jbndlr: Since Django uses a Python module for config, that's the closest example to your setup; they just use `from module import *` to merge configuration, like I advocate here.

Comment: Right, my approach is not as explicit as a design should probably be. I went this way becaus I tried to keep things as simple as possible. But probably, writing local config files that magically override the default ones on a per-package-basis is not that simple anymore. Thanks for the advice -- however, if there are other approaches, I'm still curious to see them.